# What is the point of androids?

Tags: science-fiction, artificial-intelligence, android

In a setting where humans, cyborgs, and androids coexist, with androids having robotic rights, thus removing slave labor, what other purpose could androids serve? Space exploration may be an option, but aside from this as well, what purpose could they serve as earthbound creations?

Comment: You lack some imagination if you can't possibly fathom why you might want super strong/fast/intelligent slaves which you pay for once, never feed, and work for you all day and night for several years. That would lead to their creation, anyway. Then they could gain rights, etc. Also, it's not our job to justify your world, or in this case, the world from Bladerunner.

Comment: People want slaves as long as they can justify the morality of it. So robot slaves is exactly why we would have androids. We have plenty of robot slaves today and the only reason we don't have androids is because we can't make them yet. There might not be a need for androids in your story or your world so it really doesn't matter if you have them or not.

Comment: Do you mean androids as human-looking robots sharing the same environment with humans, or "droids" which can be non human-like and serve in any kind of environment? You can imagine a futuristic world without the former, but not the latter.

Comment: I've answered three times here to try to make a point about questions involving the word "Why".  Simply stated, you don't need them.  But once you decide that they wont be slaves, then once they exist, you are stuck with them.  Any entity with full human rights gets to stay even if they serve no purpose in the world.  All you need is a convenient excuse which explains how they got created, and then they get to remain because anything else would be murder.   ...and as I have proven, reasons for their creation are plentiful.

Comment: @AndreiROM It's not that I lack imagination. I just find the slave aspect cliche. Androids would have rights. I'm just wondering what other purpose they could serve.

Comment: @Alexander Yes. I made an edit regarding planetary colonization. While it would be a useful concept, I'm seeking an earthbound approach. My apologies for not being clearer.

Comment: When trying to come up with an answer to this, you might want to ask yourself, "what's the point of humans?" Because the two questions are closely related.

Comment: The point of androids? They make a good story line. Otherwise, not really useful.

Comment: I have never encountered a sci-fi work that involved androids, where the android became 'like a human' in order to be successful. So why not bypass them entirely, and stick to human? You end up there anyway. And since the humans always win anyway, what's the point?

Comment: @Justin Thyme Well, in some SF, androids develop empathy, which tends to be what makes them human. But, androids are a reality, and I would like to have a country in my universe where humans, androids, and cyborgs are common groups.

Comment: It is a well accepted meme in sci-fi. There is nothing wrong with it as a plot device or a plot scenario. I'm just saying that any attempt to justify them is prone to, well, absurdity, and is best left alone. They are, they exist, don't try to justify them. It will only ruin the story. It's like trying to justify buying a Pet Rock.

Answer (score 2):

Because creating a synthetic life form which can tolerate the environments of the planets which we have is easier than terra-forming those planets to have the environment we want.  For that matter, our own planet's ocean floors and mountain tops are unoccupied by human life because of our biological frailty.  Synthetic humans could be created to colonize those unused spaces.

Then, if we don't make them slaves, they are free to live where they want, so some of them will, of-course, live among us.

Comment: Good concept, but I'm going to edit my question to be a little more precise.

Answer (score 2):

Tech is first developed mostly for altruistic reasons or in direct answer to an impending problem. It's further development and exploitation are driven by what we euphemistically label "market forces" or base human vices to be direct.

Broadband and video compression are two cases in point. Initially developed for research or "higher" reasons, they were driven and financed in large part by the adult entertainment industry (src: I worked there). Think back to the late 90s. You need faster speeds to download data faster and unless you collect Linux ISOs then video files are the usually the largest you'll access in those days.

Now, what is the most popular content on downloaded video files?? Porn. So suddenly the porn industry has a vested interest in getting their content to the consumer quicker. That means faster line speeds and smaller files, so they invest in video compression and xDSL technologies.

So androids....Same sorta deal. The Westworld TV series has tapped this pretty well. Androids are developed for research or altruistic reasons, but their widespread use is to sate human society's baser appetites, humans either fight the androids or fuck them, simple as that. The money they pay for that privilege may help fund further android development and that is why the android creators can tolerate their machines being used in such a degrading manner.

Androids are like the ultimate canaries in cages. You can (ab)use them to the point of destruction with no consequences. You can use them for serious purposes or just for shits and giggles, they're not human so who cares ?

Comment: It sounds like you know your stuff. I understand some people would see androids as objects and dismiss any notion about robotic rights. What extent could this abuse go without being treated as illegal activity?

Answer (score 2):

#### Same as ours

Once they exist with the ability to make more of themselves they don't need a reason to exist. They will propagate themselves for themselves. And if they have rights we wouldn't be allowed to wipe them out.

#### You can never find good help.

The reason they look like people is to interact with people. Robot butlers, prostitutes, waiters and whatnot were made to guaranty service standards better than humans, the laws of robotics seeming like good things. But for some reason that didn't work out.

Maybe the software update server was hacked and not-quite-rogue AI was disseminated which resisted being removed. Maybe the economics didn't pan out well, so the owners lobbied to give them freedom to not have to pay for maintenance or disposal. Maybe the political solution to humans being displaced from jobs by androids was to have them join the union with all the rights and responsibilities.

#### But I only made one!

Because someone could. A hobbyist makes an android and it turned out to be as technically competent as its maker. When the hobbyist comes back from a vacation the house is overrun with them. In the resulting confusion the courts name them people.

Comment: The second concept is rather interesting. Maybe I'm ignorant, but would a mechanical brain be hackable? Or, perhaps a better question: what makes hacking a machine possible?

Comment: Computer systems are generally considered to be hackable. Is there some reason androids wouldn't be? There I posit that they have software that is changeable remotely, with means hacking them is just hacking an internet server, and so far that seems to be fairly common.

Comment: I'm not opposed to hacking. I would just want to make sure if I went that route, I could come up with a plausible event.

Answer (score 2):

**Start with our own world...**

Right now we are working on creating androids. The developed countries are ageing. Their population grows old and needs caretakers who are scarce now and going to be even scarcer in the future. Moreover, countries like Japan discourage immigration and promote robotisation of the hospitality services, including nursing.

There is quite some effort put in the development of [humanoid robots](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Humanoid_robot). Many of them are envisioned as personal helpers or caregivers. [Humans are fine with robots looking like robots when it comes to cleaning and reminders](http://www.news.gatech.edu/2013/04/29/how-would-you-your-assistant-human-or-robotic). However, they prefer other humans when it comes to direct assistance and physical contact. So it makes sense to create androids that look, talk, and behave like humans.

**... and then give it an androids rights movement backstory**

Your android population might start as rather primitive but human-looking robots. But as time progresses, their AI becomes more sophisticated, their thinking evolves, and eventually, they are capable of making independent decisions. Either androids themselves or their emotionally attached owners start android rights movement which in one way or another wins.

There is no need to focus on details of backstory. It also does not have to be bloody. The Android Liberation can be achieved by lawyers and wealthy androids.  It might even start with someone rich and lonely willing their money to an android caregiver and courts initially opposing it.

**The present time: a normal society inclusive of androids, humans, and cyborgs**

Since there was no AI or android uprising, there is no problem with 'robotic overlords' or human resistance to them. It took some time (about a century), but humans, robots, and human-robot hybrids have learnt how to co-exist together. There is still might be some tension, especially since androids are overrepresented in certain fields, but most people see 'Earth for Humans' movement as unproductive and radical.

---

I think that instead of focusing on justifying the presence of androids you might want to think about the cultural and social changes that will happen in a society with a more inclusive membership. Androids will most likely think and act differently from humans. They might also have different personal goals. There also will be some android-specific crime, occupations, living and working accommodations, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

**Human minds.**

Our flesh wears out.  It is frustrating to have to age and die.  But if you can have a robot body with a digital mind, you can sidestep this problem.  An android is a robot that resembles a human, but the provenance of its mind is not specified.  It might be a human mind.

In this scenario, androids could most simply be the refuge for the old and sick, to escape death.   Or for those who tire of their original flesh and want something different.  Or many things different and more - put on a new body like a change of clothes.  Or long distance travelers - light is the best thing for traveling long distances and if a mind can be transmitted as a signal and received in a distant android body, people can visit from great distances.  Human minds could inhabit android bodies in environments where humans bodies would rapidly be destroyed - the deep sea, or Venus, or space.  Or the androids might be alien creations, built according to transmitted specifications to receive alien minds from a distant world who wanted to live among us.

Answer (score 1):

After the singularity, our new AI-Overlord wanted children created in its own image.  So it created android replicants.  Then, content that digital intelligence was properly represented in the real world, it returned to cyberspace and hasn't been heard from since.

Comment: This one actually sounds pretty good. Somewhat ominous.

Answer (score 1):

They were created as a peaceful effort towards creating a post-scarcity society, but then soft-hearted decision makers gave them rights equal to any human, thus ending the dream of post-scarcity.

Alternatively, they were created by a diabolical business owner who was attempting to create a new slave class and thus corner the labor market.  Then those same soft-hearted decision makers gave the androids rights equal to any human...